# Function arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am coming from python and trying to learn JavaScript. I noticed that when, by accident, I tried to call a function with the wrong number of arguments, it didn't raised an error and just returned `Nan`.

What's the explanation for this behavior?

EDIT: [Get warning when passing too few arguments to a javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364881/get-warning-when-passing-too-few-arguments-to-a-javascript-function)

This is exaclty what i was looking for, thank you @Code-Apprentice

Comment: In Javascript the function arguments can be accessed by index. There is no strong argument signature.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. It sounds like you are asking about two different things: what happens when you pass too many or too few arguments and why does the function return `Nan`.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364881/get-warning-when-passing-too-few-arguments-to-a-javascript-function

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that's it, thank you man

Answer (score 0):

You should add an example or code part of what you mean when you're asking a question. Anywayyyy... For your question you can read about this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp).

TL;DR?

**Parameter Rules**

JavaScript function definitions do not specify data types for parameters.

JavaScript functions do not perform type checking on the passed arguments.

JavaScript functions do not check the number of arguments received.

Comment: W3Schools is not a very good reference. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) is better